# Авторизация через Facebook

Tags: facebook, objective-c, авторизация, ios

При просмотре приложений, существующих в AppStore, я наблюдаю, что есть два способа авторизации через Facebook:

1. При нажатии на "Войти через FB" вы попадаете на сайт через веб-форму (UIWebView) и вводите туда свои email/пароль и возвращаетесь обратно.
2. При нажатии на "Войти через FB" приложение запрашивает доступ к FB-аккаунту самого телефона, и ни на какой сайт идти не нужно.

Было бы интересно узнать, как делается второй способ. Добавлю, что про первый способ я знаю и делал его уже давно, а теперь при очевидном удобстве второго способа просто хочу сэкономить время на поисках решения, как его реализовать.

**Итак, как реализовать авторизацию через FB местными средствами, без перехода на сайт FB?**

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Присоединяюсь к ребятам.

Все делается через Facebook iOS SDK, и этот SDK сам смотрит что делать и как вести себя:

Если юзер ввел данные в системный аккаунт, то будет использован он, в противном случае SDK попытается открыть Facebook App, если же приложение не установлено, то откроет Safari.

Чтобы в приложение можно было вернуться после авторизации через Safari или Facebook App, то в Info.plist нужно добавить поддержку URL-схемы, вида fb$app_id.

В принципе все довольно тривиально и неоднократно расписано, но я бы хотел поделиться немного другим опытом, а именно тем как связать iOS app с серверным backend'ом и на что можно наступить.

Это не единственно-верное решение, но на мой взгляд вполне приемлемое и достаточно "секурное".

В мобильном приложении нужно получить данные юзера:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error)
 {
     if (session.isOpen && _successCallback) {
         _successCallback(session.accessTokenData.accessToken);
     } else if (_failureCallback) {
         _failureCallback([[TDError alloc] initWithError:error]);
     }
 }];
```

вытащить auth_token и отправить его на сервер, после чего серверное приложение должно постучаться куда-то вроде `facebook.com/api/me` с этим токеном, и если пришли валидные данные, то у нас есть все чтобы зарегистрировать нового юзера, либо найти старого и залогинить его.

**P.S.** в момент когда юзер вылогинивается из мобильного приолжения, нужно также сбрасывать сессию в FB SDK, потому что оно кеширует сессию, и если юзер что-то поменял в вебе на FB (например дропнул доступ приложения), то на девайсе все равно вернется открытая сессия и токен, но то что токен невалидный выяснится только на сервере)

Очистка FB сессии:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

**З.Ы.** Прошу простить, если я что-то неправильно написал и ввел в заблуждение :)

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего пункт 2 делается через [Account Framework](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-6-tutorial-integrating-facebook-your-applications) - он позволяет работать с аккаунтами некоторых сервисов через настройки девайса, а не приложения, для фейсбука эта опция актуальна только с 6.0 потому я ее не использовал (но использовал аналогичную от твиттера, там есть свои проблемы), первый же способ идет через сторонний (для айоси) [сдк фейсбука](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), впрочем, последние его версии вроде бы тоже задействуют вариант 2 в зависимости от версии оси, врать не буду, не помню, последние полгода с этой темой не сталкивался

Answer (score 1):

Это делается через Facebook SDK. Авторизация через FB-аккаунт на телефоне производится в случае, если установлено официальное приложение Facebook. То есть, при нажатии на кнопку авторизации в Вашем приложении, открывается приложение Facebook и просит разрешения дать доступ Вашему приложению к информации в Facebook и затем авторизует. При повторной авторизации приложение Facebook уже не будет открываться а только лишь возьмет данные из Keychain, которые facebook sdk сохранил.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы скорее лишь уточняете мой вопрос, рассказывая более детально, как производится авторизация по второму способу. То, что это делается через Facebook SDK, тоже весьма очевидно (по первому тоже он используется, кстати). Меня интересует, например, конкретная ссылка на документацию и (желательно) содержательный пример с несколькими строками кода. Можете, пожалуйста, сделать ваш ответ более детальным?

Comment: Если нужно через Facebook SDK - то я думаю Вы знаете как это сделать.
Вот мой пример:
https://gist.github.com/leoru/6866165

А также, можно вытащить через Accounts.framework

https://gist.github.com/leoru/6866278

Comment: Ага, спасибо за примеры. Выглядит здраво. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Я попробовал Accounts.Framework - использовал почти тот самый код, что у вас в gist. Блок completion: срабатывает и я получаю и facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken и facebookAccount.username, который равен моему е-мэйлу, то есть вроде всё работает. Но мне остаётся немного непонятно, откуда эти данные берутся? Они ведь берутся с телефона? Если да, то почему я вообще не вижу никакого предупреждения (всплывающего окошка) о том, что приложение запрашивает доступ там куда-то к аккаунту?

Comment: В Settings есть раздел Facebook. Там вводятся данные для фейсбук-аккаунта, для того чтобы интегрировать его с системой. Данные хранятся в  Keychain.

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Удивило просто, что всё происходит "без спроса меня", то есть пользователя, ведь при авторизации первым способом я хотя бы ввожу майл/пароль, а тут всё происходит как бы за сценой.

Answer (score 1):

Используй Cocoapods.

pod 'SimpleAuth/Facebook'

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SimpleAuth

Если нужно использовать аккаунт с телефона используй конфигурацию "facebook", если через UIWebView используй "facebook-web"

Не забываем указать редирект в коде и в настройках приложения на developer.facebook.com

```
SimpleAuth.configuration[@"facebook"] = @{@"app_id":@"123456789",
 SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey : @"http://com.server.redirecturl"
 };

 [SimpleAuth authorize:@"facebook" completion:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"\nResponse: %@\nError:%@", responseObject, error);
 }];
```